# Python - Returning single value from 2-argument recursive call

Tags: python, recursion

So I'm trying to make a simple program that checks whether or not there's 2 8s in a row in a number. I know I can simply do

```
def double_eights(n):
    return '88' in str(n)
```

but I wanted to try writing the recursive method below

```
def double_eights(n, counter=0):
    #base cases
    if counter == 2:
        return True
    if n == 0:
        return False
    #recursive calls
    if n % 10 == 8:
        return(double_eights(n//10, counter + 1))
    else:
        return(double_eights(n//10), 0)
```

However, while this returns the right results, due to the way the arguments are passed in, sometimes it returns a tuple with a 0 for all the non-8 numbers that it passes. For example:

```
>>> double_eights(2882)
(True, 0)
>>> double_eights(80808080)
((((False, 0), 0), 0), 0)
```

Is there a way for the function to return only the `True` or `False` value without needing to parse the returned tuples?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's a simple typo - `double_eights(n//10), 0` should be `double_eights(n//10, 0)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the last line of your code. You return result of `double_eights(n//10)` call and `0`, so these values are packed in `tuple`.

You can change last line of your code to

```
return(double_eights(n//10, 0))
```

to specify `counter` value, but it is not necessery, because `counter` has default value

```
def double_eights(n, counter=0):
```

so you don't need to specify it. Final code may look like:

```
def double_eights(n, counter=0):
    #base cases
    if counter == 2:
        return True
    if n == 0:
        return False
    #recursive calls
    if n % 10 == 8:
        return(double_eights(n//10, counter + 1))
    else:
        return(double_eights(n//10))
```

Output:

```
double_eights(2882)
True
double_eights(80808080)
False
```